# Dynamic @JsonSubTypes When Parsing Java JSON

Tags: java, json

I have a system that involves dynamic @JsonSubTypes contributors and I'm trying to figure out how to refactor my code (example below) to not use the @JsonSubTypes annotation but instead provide these values dynamically or in runtime. Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
   @JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Researched this and there are a couple of different approaches that can be taken, the one that made the most sense is declaring this annotation on a base class that will have different sub class implementations.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
```

This will add a "@class" meta field into the serialized JSON that is then used when deserializing to determine what subclass is being used. Only down side is having to include the field when composing manual JSON.

Comment: Thanks, Really helpful. Having  

`
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat")
})
`

sometimes defeat the OpenClose Principal, Using this 

`
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
`
helps in easy extension

Comment: @SantoshJoshi Glad it helped, sometimes serializing JSON that involves sub classes is difficult this helps!